# How do I simplify mockito/hamcrest argument matchers in test method?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito, hamcrest

The test method below appear in a [spring-guide tutorial](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-web/blob/master/5/complete/src/test/java/com/yummynoodlebar/web/controller/CheckoutIntegrationTest.java).
Is there a less convoluted syntax to write this test or how can I break it apart into smaller chunks?

```
verify(orderService).createOrder(
      org.mockito.Matchers.<CreateOrderEvent>argThat(
        allOf( org.hamcrest.Matchers.<CreateOrderEvent>
            hasProperty("details",
                hasProperty("dateTimeOfSubmission", notNullValue())),

        org.hamcrest.Matchers.<CreateOrderEvent>hasProperty("details",
                hasProperty("name", equalTo(CUSTOMER_NAME))),

        org.hamcrest.Matchers.<CreateOrderEvent>hasProperty("details",
                hasProperty("address1", equalTo(ADDRESS1))),
        org.hamcrest.Matchers.<CreateOrderEvent>hasProperty("details",
                hasProperty("postcode", equalTo(POST_CODE)))
    )));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could switch the hasProperty and the allOf matchers.

```
verify(orderService).createOrder(
      org.mockito.Matchers.<CreateOrderEvent>argThat(
        org.hamcrest.Matchers.<CreateOrderEvent>hasProperty("details",
          allOf(
            hasProperty("dateTimeOfSubmission", notNullValue()),
            hasProperty("name", equalTo(CUSTOMER_NAME)),
            hasProperty("address1", equalTo(ADDRESS1)),
            hasProperty("postcode", equalTo(POST_CODE)))
    )));
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use an argument captor to record the argument value you're trying to verify.

Then you can perform assertions on the value as you see fit. This is a much clearer way of verifying the argument information is what is expected than using matchers.

This is explained more fully in the this great blog entry:

http://www.planetgeek.ch/2011/11/25/mockito-argumentmatcher-vs-argumentcaptor/

Comment: Yes, I had an answer half written when you posted this.  But this solution is much better than what I was going to write.  +1.